# Running Java equivalent of "docker exec -ti {container} curl"

Tags: java, docker, nginx, cucumber

I have a docker container configured to run Nginx and redirect traffic. I'm running acceptance tests outside the docker container and need my URL requests to be redirected.

Currently running "docker exec -ti {container} curl" from command line returns my intended response, however my Unirest HTTP client isn't sending requests through the container (as I haven't told it to, not sure how/if I can).

I think my solution would be to programatically create "docker exec curl" requests in my tests to achieve this outcome but cannot seem to find how. If someone has an idea how to achieve this it would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you export the port using `-p` or `-P` option and test directly using host URL?

Comment: I had initially tried doing this exporting port 80, however Nginx is already using that port on the container. Unless there's a way to allow both to be used, I'm somewhat new to containerization.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic port mapping for this

```
$ ID=$(docker run -P -d nginx)

$ PORT=$(docker port $ID | grep "80/tcp" | cut -d":" -f2)

$ curl http://localhost:${PORT}/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```